# For in object typescript, how I can get the name of the object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a `for()` to verify the first field in my template that have the status **INVALID** and I need the name of this object.

I try something like:

```
for(var campoObrigatorio in formulario.controls){

  if(formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio].status == "INVALID"){
    var displayCampoObrigatorio = formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio];
    console.log(displayCampoObrigatorio)
    return ;
  }

}
```

Apparently my logic is right, but i'm not getting the name of my object in this line:

```
var displayCampoObrigatorio = formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio];
```

Here are catch the dom three for the object that have the status **INVALID**, I need only the name of the object. Example: altura, comprimento, etc...

[image]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use for...of statement instead of for...in .
So your code should look like that:

```
for(var campoObrigatorio of formulario.controls){

  if(campoObrigatorio.status == "INVALID"){
    console.log(campoObrigatorio);
    return 
  }

}
```

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects,
>   including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments
>   or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It
>   invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
>   **value of each distinct property of the object**.

More about for..of [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Answer (score 0):

You in fact **have** the property name in your loop out of the box, it actually corresponds to `var campoObrigatorio`, so this should do what you want:

```
for(var campoObrigatorio in formulario.controls){
  if (formulario.get(campoObrigatorio).status === "INVALID") { // I like to use get
    console.log(campoObrigatorio) // here is the name of the form control!
    return;
  }
}
```